# How to get parent object in admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

django 1.8

models.py

```
class hotel(models.Model):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class items(models.Model):
    items_id = models.ForeignKey("hotel")

class Sell(models.Model):
    orderform = models.ForeignKey("Orderform")
    sell_id = models.ForeignKey("sell", limit_choices_to={'hotel_id': items.items_id})
    sell_count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

admin.py

```
class itemsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Sell
    extra = 1

class itemsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines= [itemsInline]
```

I want get items model items_id field

Example

```
<hotel:1> items_set have [<sell:banana>,<sell:apple>]
<hotel:2> items_set have [<sell:grapes>,<sell:starfruit>]
```

if open the url /admin/myapp/items/1/

can set `items_id` to `1`

return results `[<sell:banana>,<sell:apple>]`